# Proof that hazard rate of random variable with bounded support diverges

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Numerically it appears that the hazard rate of a random variable with bounded support diverges. But I am struggling to formally prove this.

Formally: let $y$ be a random variable with distribution $G$ and density $g$. I assume that the support is upper-bounded with $\bar y = G^{-1}(1) < \infty$. Then I want to show that,
$$
\frac{g(y)}{1-G(y)} \to \infty \;\text{as}\; y \to \bar{y}
$$

For random variables with unbounded support, we know that $\frac{-\log(1-G(y))}{y}$ behaves the same as the above in the limit (as can be seen using L'Hôpital's rule). But I am not sure how to prove divergence in the bounded case.

Comment: The distribution function $G$ should be left continuous at $\bar{y}$ since you assume $G(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y g(x)\,dx\,.$ Therefore $\lim_{y\to\bar{y}}G(y)=1\,.$ The only missing link is now that L'Hospital's rule -as far as I know- assumes $G$ to be continuously differentiable. If you assume that you are done. If not the rule might be true for left differntiable $G$ as well (your $y$ clearly approaches $\bar{y}$ from the left).